# Blanking out cstrings in a loop

Tags: c

I am trying to iterate through `char*`

Is there any way to like reset these `char*` strings back to blank?

I am trying to reset from1 and send1.

**Is there anything else wrong with my code.. it is only copying the first file in my array**

```
 for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
     from1 = " ";
     send1 = " ";
     from1 = strncat(fileLocation,filesToExport[i],50);
     send1 = strncat(whereAmI,filesToExport[i],50);

     CopyFile(from1,send1,TRUE);
     printf("%s\n",from1);
     printf("%s",send1);
 }
```

Comment: which char* strings?? strings in filesToExport array?

Comment: I'm convinced this code is wrong, you can't reuse fileLocation in this way.


Please see my suggeestion below

Answer (score 3):

THe strings are nul terminated, which means they have a zero character at the end. You can set the first char in the string to zero to truncate it back to being empty:

```
from1[0] = '\0';
```

Another way would be to copy a blank string:

```
strcpy(from1, "");
```

Comment: I totally agree with Steven. char is the correct type here. Thanks for using the correct literal. :D

Comment: This will put a null at the beginning of filelocation, hence next time round the loop its wrong! Either put teh null at the end the original filelocation or use a separate buffer.

Comment: file location appears to be the directory part of the destination, we just zapped it.    C:/dir/  was strncatted to C:/dir/theFileToCopy

Next time round the loop we wat to put the null at position 7, over the t of theFileToCopy not at 0 over the C of C:

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "blank"? Zeroed, spaces, or empty?

For filling a memory area you're best off using memset(), so

```
#include <string.h>

memset(pBuffer, ' ', length); /* Fill with spaces */
pBuffer[length] = '\0'; /* Remember to null-terminate manually when using memset */ 

memset(pBuffer, '\0', length); /* Fill with zeroes */

pBuffer[0] = '\0'; /* Set first element to null -- effectively set the string 
                    * to length 0
                    */
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set the first byte to 0. Like this:

```
from1[0] = 0;
send1[0] = 0;
```

C/C++ checks the end of a `char*` string by looking for the 0 byte. It doesn't care what follows that.

Answer (score 1):

To clear a string to empty, so that `strncat()` has an empty string to concatenate to, just do:

```
from1[0] =  '\0';
```

This sets the first character to the zero terminator that indicates end of string, thus making the string have length 0. This assumes that `from1` is an actual modifiable `char` buffer, but your call to `strncat()` implies that it is.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying into `filelocation` and `whereami`. Are they buffers or strings? You may be writing off the end of your string.

I think you would do better to allocate a suitably sized buffer

```
fromLen = strlen(fileLocation);
fileLen = strlen(filesToExport[i]);

from1 = malloc(fromLen + fileLen + 1);

/* add check here that string fits */

strcpy( from1, filelocation);
strcat( from1 + fromLen, filesToExport[i]);

/** etc **/

free(from1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean like

```
send1[0] = 0;
from1[0] = 0;
```

?